# Exist an equivalent lib to window.crypto.subtle.importKey in python3

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, cryptojs, pycrypto

**For example in js**

```
window.crypto.subtle.importKey("jwk", object, object, false, ["encrypt"]);
```

In python:

```
?????
```

**Encrypt in js with the imported key**

```
window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(object, object, function (e) {....}
```

In python:

```
???
```